# how to delete first charecter of second column if it starts with zero

Tags: unix

I have a fixed width file like this:

```
FY14Working          BCT86   DI                Mattel Brands                      69.9900
FY14Working          BCT86   DC                Mattel Brands                      87.4900
FY14Working          0CT90   DC                Mattel Brands                      31.2400
FY14Working          BCK16   DC                Mattel Brands                      27.4900
FY14Working          0CT89   DC                Mattel Brands                      31.2400
FY14Working          BCK14   DC                Mattel Brands                      58.7400
FY14Working          01234   DC                Mattel Brands                      66.2400
```

I want to delete Zero from the second column IF IT IS IN FIRST POSITION IN SECOND COLUMN.

OUTPUT should be like this :

```
FY14Working          BCT86   DI                Mattel Brands                      69.9900
FY14Working          BCT86   DC                Mattel Brands                      87.4900
FY14Working          CT90   DC                Mattel Brands                      31.2400
FY14Working          BCK16   DC                Mattel Brands                      27.4900
FY14Working          CT89   DC                Mattel Brands                      31.2400
FY14Working          BCK14   DC                Mattel Brands                      58.7400
FY14Working          1234   DC                Mattel Brands                      66.2400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should make:

```
awk '{gsub(/^0/,"",$2)}1' file
```

To keep the format, add `| column -t`:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^0/,"",$2)}1' file | column -t
FY14Working  BCT86  DI  Mattel  Brands  69.9900
FY14Working  BCT86  DC  Mattel  Brands  87.4900
FY14Working  CT90   DC  Mattel  Brands  31.2400
FY14Working  BCK16  DC  Mattel  Brands  27.4900
FY14Working  CT89   DC  Mattel  Brands  31.2400
FY14Working  BCK14  DC  Mattel  Brands  58.7400
FY14Working  1234   DC  Mattel  Brands  66.2400
```